# how connect with web service

Tags: json, web-services, jquery

I am trying to get some data from a web service:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://192.******.asmx?op=GetJSONString",
    method: "serverCallback",
    data: "Select con.cod as codigo, con.res as descripcion from con where ide>0",
    success: function(data){alert(data)},    
});
```

How can I get the returned JSON data?

Comment: Need a jQuery tag for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what my calls look like. Can you be more specific of the issue you are having?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    data: "SOME DATA",      
    dataType: "json",
    url : "/myapp/service.json",
    cache: false,
    error: function() {     
                         alert("There was an issue");
        }
    ,
    success: function(data) 
    {                   
            processJson(data); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I will also post what has worked with me for asmx services.

In the example below, for  "url": "/service/Details.asmx/Reject", the "/Reject" is the method name in the web service (asmx) file.

```
  $.ajax({
            "dataType": 'json',
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "type": "POST",
            "url": "/service/Details.asmx/Reject",
            "data": "{\"itemId\":\"" + id + "\",\"comment\":\"" + comms + "\"}",
            "success":
                        function (msg) {
                          alert("Yea it worked!");
                            });
                        }
        });
```

Comment: and where/how I can write my sql sentence?

Comment: Mike, sending the entire sql statement through the "data": is not very secure, this can leave you vulnerable to injection attacks and cross site scripting.  Only send back certain details of the query that change and leave the rest of the query in the code behind.  In my example, itemId and comment are the only things that change in my query, in my code behind I take those values and plug them into a string to build the sql query. Data being sent from the ajax "data": must be valid JSON, use JSONLint.com. Test returned data for invalid chars using reg expressions to remove injections, XSS

Comment: thanks. we will use this service only for select querys, is there any security problem?

Comment: Mike, did you get the data sent back to the web service? The query can be highjacked, meaning somebody can send any query they ant to the web service and the service will run it unless you are validating it somehow on the back end to make sure there are no other SQl keywords that would add, drop or create any data. Even so, they could query your entire db, so if you have sensitive data on there, you may want to lock it down.

Comment: Ok Thank you I will rethink this project with your council